# Logstash - Parse XML attributes

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, xpath, logstash

I am trying to parse and send field names to ElasticSearch and am running into issue with getting the correct fields lined up.

Here is some sample XML

```
<products>
<product name="name_1"></product>
<product name="name_2"></product>
<product name="name_3"></product>
</products>
```

My logstash config file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "sample.xml"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        exclude => "*.gz"
        type => "xml"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "<products>"
            negate => "true"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        target => "products"
        add_field => {
            "p_name" => "%{[products][product][name]}"
        }
        xpath => [
            "/products/*/@name", "product_name"
        ]
    }
}
```

Currently, in ElasticSearch: there is a single `p_name`set to `%{[products][product][name]}` and `product_name` is `name_1, name_2, name_3`

Instead, I would like to have 3 different records, each having their own unique `product_name`

What is correct xml filter?

Comment: I think you should be able to do it with the split [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html), using `p_name` as the field parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue (rather, what I thought I was ingesting) started with reading the input incorrectly. Below is my logstash.config file.

Instead of ingesting on the `<products>` attribute, I went directly to the `<product>` attribute. This meant that each incoming line was a single product (and its sub-elements).

```
input {
    file {
        path => /file/example*.xml"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        type => "xml"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "<product>"
            negate => "true"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
        store_xml => false
        xpath => [
            "/product/@name", "name"
        ]
    }
}
```